# A data structure for Logical Expressions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I try to create a data structure for working with logical expressions. At first glance, the logical expressions look like `Trees`, so it seems reasonable to make up it from trees:

```
data Property a = And (Property a) (Property a) |
                 Or  (Property a) (Property a) |
                 Not (Property a) | Property a   deriving (Show,Eq)
```

But it isn't a good idea, because really there is no difference between left and right branches of my tree, since `A && B == B && A`

Well, maybe `List` is even better?

```
data Property a = Empty | And a (Property a) | Or a (Property a) | Not a (Property a)  deriving Show
```

But in this case, I can't really form a 'logic tree', only a 'logic list '.
So I need a data structure similar to `Tree` but without left and right "branching".

Comment: I recommend the naive representation (your first one), plus a function `canonicalize :: Property a -> Property a` that [picks one of the famous normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).

Comment: Another choice, with its own merits and demerits, is to jump straight to the denotation: `type Property a = (a -> Bool) -> Bool`. Whether that's reasonable depends a lot on what operations you want to be able to perform on a `Property a`... can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: I work on query to query matching, so my first idea was to build logical trees, canonicalize it by any way and match two trees.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We're going to follow Daniel Wagner's excellent suggestion and use the "naive representation (your first one), plus a function that picks one of the famous normal forms". We are going to use [algebraic normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) for two reasons. The main reason is that algebraic normal form doesn't require enumerating all the possible values of the variable type held in a `Property`. Algebraic normal form is also fairly simple.

#### Algebraic Normal Form

We'll represent algebraic normal form with a `newtype ANF a = ANF [[a]]` that doesn't export its constructor. Each inner list is a conjunction (and-ing) of all of its predicates; if an inner list is empty it is always true. The outer list is an exclusive or-ing of all of its predicates; if it is empty it is false.

```
module Logic (
    ANF (getANF),
    anf,
    ...
)

newtype ANF a = ANF {getANF :: [[a]]}
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

We will make efforts so that any `ANF` we construct will be canonical. We will build `ANF`s so that the inner list is always sorted and unique. The outer list will also always be sorted. If there are two (or an even number of) identical items in the outer list we will remove them both. If there are an odd number of identical items in the outer list, we will remove all but one of them.

Using functions from [`Data.List.Ordered`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) in the [data-ordlist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) package, we can clean up a list of lists representing the xor-ing of conjunctions into an `ANF` with the lists sorted and duplicates removed.

```
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as Ordered

anf :: Ord a => [[a]] -> ANF a
anf = ANF . nubPairs . map Ordered.nubSort

nubPairs :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nubPairs = removePairs . Ordered.sort
    where
        removePairs (x:y:zs)
            | x == y    = removePairs zs
            | otherwise = x:removePairs (y:zs)
        removePairs xs = xs
```

Logical expressions form a [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)), which is a bounded lattice with an additional distributive law and a complement (negation). Taking advantage of the existing [`BoundedLattice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lattices-1.2.1.1/docs/Algebra-Lattice.html#t:BoundedLattice) class in the [lattices](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lattices) package, we can define the class of `BooleanAlgebra`s

```
import Algebra.Lattice

class (BoundedLattice a) => BooleanAlgebra a where
    complement :: a -> a
    -- Additional Laws:
    -- a `join` complement a == top
    -- a `meet` complement a == bottom
    -- a `join` (b `meet` c) == (a `join` b) `meet` (a `join` c)
    -- a `meet` (b `join` c) == (a `meet` b) `join` (a `meet` c)
```

`ANF a`s form a `BooleanAlgebra` whenever `a` has an `Ord` instance so that we can keep the `ANF` in canonical form.

The `meet` of a boolean algebra is logical `and`. Logical `and` distributes across `xor`. We will take advantage of the fact that the inner lists are already sorted to quickly merge them together distinctly.

```
instance (Ord a) => MeetSemiLattice (ANF a) where
    ANF xs `meet` ANF ys = ANF (nubPairs [Ordered.union x y | x <- xs, y <- ys])
```

Using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the `join` or logical `or` can be written in terms of the `meet` or logical `and`.

```
instance (Ord a) => JoinSemiLattice (ANF a) where
    xs `join` ys = complement (complement xs `meet` complement ys)
```

The `top` of the lattice is always true.

```
instance (Ord a) => BoundedMeetSemiLattice (ANF a) where
    top = ANF [[]]
```

The `bottom` of the lattice is always false.

```
instance (Ord a) => BoundedJoinSemiLattice (ANF a) where
    bottom = ANF []
```

Logical `and` and logical `or` satisfy the lattice absorption law, `a join (a meet b) == a meet (a join b) == a`.

```
instance (Ord a) => Lattice (ANF a)
instance (Ord a) => BoundedLattice (ANF a)
```

Finally the `complement` operation is negation, which can be accomplished by `xor`ing by true.

```
instance (Ord a) => BooleanAlgebra (ANF a) where
    complement (ANF ([]:xs)) = ANF xs
    complement (ANF xs)      = ANF ([]:xs)
```

Along with [`Pointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-4.2/docs/Data-Pointed.html) we can use `BooleanAlgebra` to define the class of things that hold logical expressions, `Logical`.

```
import Data.Pointed

class Logical f where
    toLogic :: (Pointed g, BooleanAlgebra (g a)) => f a -> g a
```

Algebraic normal form holds a logical expression.

```
xor :: BooleanAlgebra a => a -> a -> a
p `xor` q = (p `join` q) `meet` complement (p `meet` q)

instance Logical ANF where
    toLogic = foldr xor bottom . map (foldr meet top . map point) . getANF
```

Algebraic normal form is also `Pointed`, and thus can be converted to using `toLogic`.

```
instance Pointed ANF where
    point x = ANF [[x]]

toANF :: (Logical f, Ord a) => f a -> ANF a
toANF = toLogic
```

We can test if anything `Logical` is logically equivalent by comparing to see if it is structurally equivalent when converted to canonical algebraic normal form.

```
equivalent :: (Logical f, Logical g, Ord a) => f a -> g a -> Bool
equivalent a b = toANF a == toANF b
```

#### Converting Property to ANF

Logical expressions should form a boolean algebra, which is a bounded lattice with an additional distributive law and a complement (negation). To make `Property` more closely parallel a boolean algebra, we need to add two more elements for the `top` and `bottom` bounds of the lattice. `top` is always `True`, and `bottom` is always `False`. I'm going to call these `Trivial` for properties that are always `True` and `Impossible` for properties that are always `False`.

```
data Property a
    = And (Property a) (Property a)
    | Or  (Property a) (Property a)
    | Not (Property a)
    | Property a
    | Trivial
    | Impossible
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

`Property` is an abstract syntax tree for a property. Its derived `Eq` and `Ord` instances are only structural equality.

A `Property` is `Logical`, and we can convert it into any `Pointed` `BooleanAlgebra`.

```
instance Logical Property where
    toLogic (And a b)    = (toLogic a) `meet` (toLogic b)
    toLogic (Or  a b)    = (toLogic a) `join` (toLogic b)
    toLogic (Not a)      = complement (toLogic a)
    toLogic (Property a) = point a
    toLogic Trivial      = top
    toLogic Impossible   = bottom
```

Using `equivalent` from the previous section and our `Logical` instance, we can check to see if two properties are equivalent for some examples.

```
runExample :: (Ord a, Show a) => Property a -> Property a -> IO ()
runExample p q = 
    if p `equivalent` q
    then putStrLn (show p ++ " == " ++ show q)
    else putStrLn (show p ++ " /= " ++ show q)

main = do
    runExample (point 'a' `meet` point 'b') (point 'b' `meet` point 'a')
    runExample (point 'a' `meet` point 'b') (point 'b' `meet` point 'a' `meet` point 'a')
    runExample (point 'a' `meet` point 'b') (point 'b' `meet` point 'a' `join` point 'a')
    runExample (point 'a' `join` complement (point 'a')) (top)
    runExample (point 'a' `meet` complement (point 'a')) (bottom)
```

This produces the following output.

```
And (Property 'a') (Property 'b') == And (Property 'b') (Property 'a')
And (Property 'a') (Property 'b') == And (And (Property 'b') (Property 'a')) (Pr
operty 'a')
And (Property 'a') (Property 'b') /= Or (And (Property 'b') (Property 'a')) (Pro
perty 'a')
Or (Property 'a') (Not (Property 'a')) == Trivial
And (Property 'a') (Not (Property 'a')) == Impossible
```

To use these examples as written, we also need `BooleanAlgebra` and `Pointed` instances for `Property`. The equivalence relation for the `BooleanAlgebra` laws is equivalent interpretations rather than the structural equality of `Property`.

```
instance MeetSemiLattice (Property a) where
    meet = And

instance BoundedMeetSemiLattice (Property a) where
    top = Trivial

instance JoinSemiLattice (Property a) where
    join = Or

instance BoundedJoinSemiLattice (Property a) where
    bottom = Impossible

instance Lattice (Property a)
instance BoundedLattice (Property a)

instance BooleanAlgebra (Property a) where
    complement = Not

instance Pointed Property where
    point = Property
```

#### Proof

Every Boolean function, and thus every finite `Property`, has a *unique* representation in `ANF`. The `BooleanAlgebra` and `Pointed` instances for `ANF` demonstrated that everything `Logical a`, and thus every finite `Property a` and Boolean function indexed by `a`, has a representation in `ANF a`. Let `k` be the number of inhabitants of `a`. There are `2^(2^k)` possible Boolean functions of `k` Boolean variables. Each inner list of an `ANF` is a set of `a`s; there are `2^k` possible sets of `a`s and thus `2^k` possible inner lists. The outer list of an `ANF` is a set of inner lists; each inner list can occur at most once in the outer list. There are `2^(2^k)` possible `ANF a`s. Since every Boolean function has a representation in `ANF` and there are only as many possible inhabitants of `ANF` as there are Boolean functions, each Boolean function has a *unique* representation in `ANF`.

#### Disclaimer

The `Ord` instance for `ANF` is a structural order and, except for equality, has nothing to do with the partial orders induced by the lattice structure.

Algebraic normal form can be exponentially larger than its input. The disjunction of a list of `n` variables has size `.5*n*2^n`. For example, `length . getANF . foldr join bottom . map point $ ['a'..'g']` is `127` and `foldr join bottom . map point $ ['a'..'g']` contains a total of `448` occurrences of the `7` different variables.

Comment: re: "you should convince yourself...", the Wikipedia page you linked says, in part, "ANF is a normal form, which means that two equivalent formulas will convert to the same ANF".

Comment: @DanielWagner A simple assertion, much less a simple uncited assertion in a Wikipedia article, is not enough to convince me. I have, so-far, failed to convince myself. Other Wikipedia articles on "normal" forms make similar claims, despite trivial counter examples. Both `(a ∧ ¬b) ∨ (a ∧ b)` and `a` are in "disjunctive normal form", and both of them mean the same thing. Disjunctive normal form as described on Wikipedia isn't really a normal form. Only specific variants of it, such as full disjunctive normal form where every variable appears in every conjunction, are normal forms.

Comment: Another interesting answer from Cirdec.

Comment: @Cirdec While I appreciate your skepticism, your criticism of Wikipedia looks unwarranted to me; the Wikipedia page for "Disjunctive normal form" is quite clear that only full disjunctive normal form is canonical, and the Wikipedia page for "Canonical normal form" looks likewise quite careful about what forms have the "equivalent formulas have the same form" property.

Comment: @phadej The question is explicitly about testing for tautological equivalence, starting with a structure very close to "negation normal form". Testing for tautological equivalence is necessarily NP hard (testing if `f == const False` is the (un)satisfiability problem), but doesn't necessarily require exponential space.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a SAT/SMT solver for the equivalence check. In general, these sorts of checks can be very expensive (NP-complete), and any sort of translation to normal-forms can cause exponential blow-up in representation. SAT/SMT solvers have custom algorithms for dealing with such problems, and it might be best to use such a solver. It would be trivial to translate two instances of `Property` and ask if they are the same under all variable assignments. SBV library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) can be used to do the translation from high-level Haskell. The answer to the following question has some details on how to go about doing that: [SAT solving with haskell SBV library: how to generate a predicate from a parsed string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233969/sat-solving-with-haskell-sbv-library-how-to-generate-a-predicate-from-a-parsed)

Comment: There's no reason to restrict the problem to `Property Bool`. The type argument to `Property` isn't the type of the result, it's the type of the index for the variables. As long as it has an `Ord` or `Eq` instance, it can be converted to another index like `Int`s in `O(n*log n)` or `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Ah, quite right. If the 'a' parameter is just indexing into variables, then indeed it would be easy to translate this to a SAT/SMT problem, and use an off-the-shelf solver to do the equivalence checking. Also note that the backend solver will return a counter-example model if the two formulas are not equivalent, which can then be used further. i.e.; the "not-equal" answer will be substantiated with a model that shows why the equivalence fails instead of a plain "no" answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect the associativity of logical connectives *and* (`&&`) and *or*, use a data structure that is associative, like list:

```
data Property a = And [Property a] | ...
```

If you also want commutativity (`A && B == B && A`), go with [Data.Set](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Set.html).

I remember this handy chart for which types to use if you want certain properties:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------
|Associative|Commutative|Idempotent|   type
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------
|(a+b)+c=   |  a+b=b+a  |  a+a=a   |
|    a+(b+c)|           |          |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------
|    no     |    no     |    no    |binary trees
|    no     |   yes     |    no    | “mobiles”
|   yes     |    no     |    no    |lists (arrays)
|   yes     |   yes     |    no    |multisets (bags)
|   yes     |   yes     |   yes    |sets
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------
```

Page 51 of [Guy Steele's Lecture](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6.945/readings/MITApril2009Steele.pdf).

Comment: And which data structure reflects deMorgan's laws...? =P