# What's an easy way to generate an SBV formula given some data using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, formula, smt

Assuming a tree in which the nodes may or may not be present, I would like to generate a formula in which:

1. there's a boolean variable for each node (to represent whether it's present or not),
2. a root if free (may or may not be present), and
3. a node can only be present if its parent is present (child implies the parent).

My goal is to generate all possible subtrees of the given shape using `allSat`. For example, consider the datatype and an example `tree`:

```
data Tree
    = Leaf
    | Tree [ Tree ]
    deriving Show

tree :: Tree
tree
    = Tree            -- T1
        [ Leaf        -- L1
        , Tree        -- T2
            [ Leaf    -- L2
            , Leaf    -- L3
            ]
        ]
```

translating that tree should introduce booleans for each node `T1, T2, L1, L2, L3` and a set of constraints:

```
L1 => T1
T2 => T1
L2 => T2
L3 => T2
```

The following code produces the right solutions (11):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- allSat . forSome ["T1", "T2", "L1", "L2", "L3"] $
        \ (t1::SBool) t2 l1 l2 l3 ->
            (   (l1 ==> t1)
            &&& (t2 ==> t1)
            &&& (l2 ==> t2)
            &&& (l3 ==> t2)
            )
    putStrLn $ show res
```

So, how can I generate the formula given to `allSat` given some concrete `tree`?

An alternative solution would be to construct the action like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- allSat $ makePredicate tree
    putStrLn $ show res

makePredicate :: Tree -> Predicate
makePredicate    _     = do
        t1 <- exists "T1"
        l1 <- exists "L1"
        constrain $ l1 ==> t1
        t2 <- exists "T2"
        constrain $ t2 ==> t1
        l2 <- exists "L2"
        constrain $ l2 ==> t2
        l3 <- exists "L3"
        constrain $ l3 ==> t2
        return true
```

EDIT: I discovered an [answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23234919/3642157), which is related. The idea would be to construct an action like in the alternative solution above but during the fold of the tree. That is possible because Symbolic is a monad.

Answer (score 1):

In order to figure out how the recursion should work, it is instructive to rewrite the alternative solution from the question to match the shape of the tree:

```
makePredicate :: Tree -> Predicate
makePredicate    _     = do
        -- SBool for root
        t1 <- exists "T1"
        -- predicates for children
        c1 <- do
                -- SBool for child
                l1 <- exists "L1"
                -- child implies the parent
                constrain $ l1 ==> t1
                return true
        c2 <- do
                t2 <- exists "T2"
                constrain $ t2 ==> t1
                -- predicates for children
                c3 <- do
                        l2 <- exists "L2"
                        constrain $ l2 ==> t2
                        return true                    
                c4 <- do
                        l3 <- exists "L3"
                        constrain $ l3 ==> t2
                        return true
                return $ c3 &&& c4 &&& true 
        return $ c1 &&& c2 &&& true
```

As we can see, we first create an `SBool` variable for a node, then process it's children, and then return a conjunction. That means we can map over children to produce their `Predicate`s first, then fold the list of the `Predicate`s with `true` as the initial value.

The following code traverses the tree and produces a formula. First, we simplify the Tree type

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.SBV

data Tree
    = Node String [ Tree ]
    deriving Show

tree :: Tree
tree
    = Node "T1"
        [ Node "L1" []
        , Node "T2"
            [ Node "L2" []
            , Node "L3" []
            ]
        ]
```

Then we recursively traverse the tree and produce a `Predicate` for each node. The root is special: because it does not have a parent, there's nothing to imply.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- allSat $ makeRootPredicate tree
    putStrLn $ show res

makeRootPredicate :: Tree       -> Predicate
makeRootPredicate    (Node i cs) = do
    x <- exists i
    cps <- mapM (makeNodePredicate x) cs
    return $ bAnd cps

makeNodePredicate :: SBool -> Tree       -> Predicate
makeNodePredicate    parent   (Node i cs) = do
    x <- exists i
    constrain $ x ==> parent
    cps <- mapM (makeNodePredicate x) cs
    return $ bAnd cps
```

Finally, I am using `bAnd` to create a conjunction of the predicates (as pointed out in the comment).

Because `bAnd` internally uses `foldr`, we get a formula

```
(c1 &&& (c2 &&& true))
```

substituting for `c1` and `c2`, we get

```
(((l1 ==> t1) &&& true) &&& (((t2 ==> t1) &&& c3 &&& c4 &&& true) &&& true))
```

substituting for `c3` and `c4`, we get

```
(((l1 ==> t1) &&& true) &&& (((t2 ==> t1) &&& ((l2 ==> t2) &&& true) &&& ((l3 ==> t2) &&& true) &&& true) &&& true))
```

As indicated in the comment, SBV will internally simplify the formula by partially evaluating it where possible. So, the `true`s will be eliminated.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, and while I do not think this is idiomatic SBV/Haskell, if it works for you then it's the best solution. Regarding the use of `&&&` in a chain: What you're looking for is the `bAnd` function: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-4.2/docs/src/Data-SBV-Utils-Boolean.html#bAnd 

SBV will internally "optimize" these nested calls by partial evaluation whenever possible, and usually such boolean constraints will have no visible effect on the underlying SMT solvers performance.

Comment: I have unaccepted the solution. I am very interested to learn the "idiomatic SBV" way. The reason I used monadic composition is because, in general, I will be traversing a rich datastructure and depending on many conditions, I'll be adding various constraints. For example, when I encounter a constraint in the form of `A excludes B`, I need to generate `constrain $ a ==> bnot b`.

Comment: I updated the solution to use `bAnd` as per @LeventErkok 's comment.